# Issue with Checkboxes and adding value in the database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to add values of some checkboxes in my database but it's not really working. It gives "" values:

[image: http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/2844/kbyl.png]

This is the query it creates:
INSERT INTO oudebadkamer(WC, Bad, Douche, Wasbak) VALUES ( '','','','');

The connection is ok and the names are correct since it adds "" in all the fields.

Please help me out.

```
 <form action="formhandle.php" method="POST">

    Wat zit er in uw huidige badkamer?<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="WC" checked>WC<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="Douche" checked>Douche<br />        
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="Bad" checked>Bad<br />  
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="Wasbak" checked>Wasbak<br />    

    <input type="submit" name="Volgende" value="Volgende"/><br />
    <?php 
    $checkbox1 = $_POST['Sanitair'];
    if(isset ($_POST ['Volgende']))
    {           
            $querystring = "INSERT INTO oudebadkamer(WC, Bad, Douche, Wasbak)
                          VALUES (
                          '"
                          .$checkbox1[0]."','"
                          .$checkbox1[1]."','"
                          .$checkbox1[2]."','"
                          .$checkbox1[3]."');";
            mysql_query($querystring)or die(mysql_error());

            echo $querystring;          
    }
    ?>  
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant code from you screenshot?

Comment: If you are getting that query, it is inserting blank values. Where are you creating your query?

Comment: Show what you have coded

Comment: @Chad he is creating the query when he defines `$querystring`

Comment: What is the name of the .php file the screenshotted code is in? @Bart

Comment: You need to `var_dump($_POST['Sanitair']);` before you assign it to `checkbox1` and make sure it's a properly formed array.

Comment: You should use PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements instead of mysql_ functions, they've been deprecated.

Comment: I've added the code Steven V

Comment: The file is named Stap1.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close you form ie. `</form>` before starting to process PHP.

i have edited your code:

It will work now !

```
<form action="formhandle.php" method="POST">

Wat zit er in uw huidige badkamer?<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="WC" checked>WC<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="Douche" checked>Douche<br />        
<input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="Bad" checked>Bad<br />  
<input type="checkbox" name="Sanitair[]" value="Wasbak" checked>Wasbak<br />    

<input type="submit" name="Volgende" value="Volgende"/><br />

</form> 
<?php 
if(isset ($_POST ['Volgende']))
{    
    $val1 =$val2 = $val3 = $val4 = FALSE; // declaring all variables to be false

    if(isset($_POST['Sanitair'][0]))
    {
        $val1 = $_POST['Sanitair'][0]; // if value is set then put the value in variable else keep it empty
    }
    else
    {
       $val1 = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Sanitair'][1]))
    {
        $val2 = $_POST['Sanitair'][1];
    }
    else
    {
       $val2 = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Sanitair'][2]))
    {
        $val3 = $_POST['Sanitair'][2];
    }
    else
    {
       $val3 = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Sanitair'][3]))
    {
        $val4 = $_POST['Sanitair'][3];
    }
    else
    {
       $val4 = '';
    }

    if($val1 or $val2 or $val3 or $val4)
    {
         $querystring = "INSERT INTO oudebadkamer (`WC`, `Bad`, `Douche`, `Wasbak`)
                      VALUES ( '".$val1."','".$val2."','".$val3."','".$val4."')";
        mysql_query($querystring)or die(mysql_error());
// use backtics with column name while inserting it will help reducing future  errors
        echo $querystring;  
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no Checkbox selected";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all fields are empty (""), then that means they are not being checked.

Check some checkboxes and maybe post the `var_dump` of `$_POST['Sanitair']`.

Comment: Used var_dump and it gives the value null. Kinda odd since I checked all the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment becouse of my low reputation but at least few tips as an answer.

1. is the file name of your page on your screenshot `formhandle.php?`
2. use `var_dump()` function to print `$_POST` array to see if ur getting the data you requested
3. names don't have to be correct becouse in PHP you dont need specify type of variable when you'r creating it even inicialize it. That means if you'r not geting anything in your `$_POST` array th`e $querystring` will still look the same `(...VALUES ( '','','','');)`

Comment: It's in a different php file. My formhandle.php file is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
if(isset($_request['Volgende']))
{
$checkbox1=$_request['Sanitair'];
After this you can use the '$checkbox1' array value in your query.
}
```